# Scaling problem with parallel words finding in text (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, nlp

I'm working in python and I have to resolve a simple task (at least with a simple definition):

I have a set of names, each name is a sequence of token: `names_to_find = ['York', 'New York', 'Dustin']`
I have a corpus, which consists of a list of sentences: `corpus = [' I love New York but also York ', ' Dustin is my cat ', ' I live in New York with my friend Dustin ']`

My desired output is a dictionary with `names_to_find` as keys and, for each occurrence in the corpus, a couple `(#sentence_index, #word_index)`

The desired output of the example is:

```
output = { 'York' : [(0, 3), (0, 6), (2, 4)], 'New York' : [(0, 2), (2, 2)], 'Dustin' : [(1, 0), (2, 8)]}
```

As you can see if the `name_to_find` appears two times in the same sentence I want both, for composed names (e.g., 'New York') I want the index of the first word.

The problem is that I have 1 million of `names_to_find` and 4.8 million of sentences in `corpus`

I made a code which does not scale in order to see if time was acceptable (it was not); to find all names in 100000 (100k) sentences my code needs 12 hours :'(

My question is twofold: I'm here to ask you to help me with my code or to paste a largely different code, it doesn't matter, the only thing that matters is that the code scales

I report my (parallel) code, here I find only single words and the composite words (i.e. 'New York') are found in another function which checks if word indexes are contiguous:

```
 def parallel_find(self, n_proc):
    """
    takes entities in self.entity_token_in_corpus and for each call the function self.entities_token_in_corpus
    this method (and the involved one) are thought to work in parallel, so after the calling a reduce is applied
    :param 
       n_proc: the number of process used to make the computation
    """
    p = Pool(n_proc)

    print('start indexing')

    t = time.time()

    index_list = p.map(self.create_word_occurrence_index, self.entities_token_in_corpus)

    t = time.time() - t

    index_list_dict = {k:v for elem in index_list for k, v in elem.items() if v}
    p.close()
    return index_list_dict, n_proc, len(self.corpus), t

def create_word_occurrence_index(self, word):
    """
    loop on all the corpus, call self.find_in_sentence to find occurrences of word in each sentence, returns a dict
    :param 
        word: the word to find
    :return: a dict with the structure: {entity_name: list of tuples (row: [occurrences in row])}
    """
    key = word
    returning_list = []
    for row_index, sent in enumerate(self.joined_corpus):
        if sent.find(' ' + word + ' ') != -1:
            indices = self.find_in_sentence(word = word, sentence = sent)
            if indices:
                returning_list.append((row_index, indices))
    return {key: returning_list}

def find_in_sentence(self, word, sentence):
    """
    returns the indexes in which the word appear in a sentence
    :params
        word: the word to find
        sentence: the sentence in which find the word
    :return: a list of indices
    """

    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if x == word]
    return indices
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You split every sentence that contains the word on every search for a word in a sentence, i.e.  a good proportion of 4.8x10^6x10^6 times, which would take a while if you had the time to wait - surely you should only split once, then use the `in` operator against the split sentence..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of 'consecutive words' you expect to search for, i.e. two words in a row only? Not three words in a row, for example? Or an indefinite amount?

Comment: The number of word is indefinite, (but I think at most 20 words). Answer for @barny, if I use the  `in` operator how can I find the index? @AMC, i'm going to attach the minimal reproducible example

Comment: Use `index()`? Main thing is to only split the sentence once, rather than for every word

Comment: index() does not account for multi-occurrence in the same sentence, it returns the last occurrence

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bre1fp4OkjhMRVe0HNknqVmv56nyjun4?usp=sharing

Comment: I uploaded the corpus, sections of corpus, 1 pickle with all names to find and a script with my code

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt using generators but I'm not sure how much better it will perform on a large target. The problematic part is the multi-word matches, but I tried to build in some multiple short-circuit and early-termination code (I think there is more to do on that, but the complexity starts building up there too):

```
def matcher(words, targets):
    for word in words:
        result = {word: []}                     #empty dict to hold each word
        if len(word.split()) == 1:              #check to see if word is single
            for t, target in enumerate(targets):
                foo = target.split()
                bar = [(t,i) for i,x in enumerate(foo) if x == word] #collect the indices
                if bar:
                    result[word].extend(bar)    #update the dict
            yield result                        #returns a generator

        else:
            consecutive = word.split()          
            end = len(consecutive)
            starter = consecutive[0]              #only look for first word match
            for t, target in enumerate(targets):
                foo = target.split()
                limit = len(foo)
                if foo.count(starter):  #skip entire target if 1st word missing
                    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(foo) if (x==starter and
                             limit - end > i)]    #don't try to match if index too high
                    bar = []
                    for i in indices:
                        if foo[i:i+end] == consecutive:   #do match (expensive)
                            bar.append((t,i))
                    result[word].extend(bar)

                else:
                    continue
            yield result
```

If you want to collect everything at one go, for this modified example

```
targets = [ ' I love New York but also York ',
            ' Dustin is my cat ',
            ' I live in New York with my friend Dustin ',
            ' New York State contains New York City aka New York']  

values =  [ 'York', 'New York', 'Dustin', 'New York State' ]

zed = matcher(values, targets)
print(list(zed))
```

Produces:

```
{'York': [(0, 3), (0, 6), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 5), (3, 9)]}
{'New York': [(0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 4)]}
{'Dustin': [(1, 0), (2, 8)]}
{'New York State': [(3, 0)]}
```

There might be ways to exploit concurrency here, I'm really not sure, not being too familiar with that as of yet. See https://realpython.com/async-io-python/ for example. Also, I didn't go over that code carefully for off-by-one errors... think its okay. Probably want some unittest here.